# How to consume 3rd Party wsdl in magento2

Tags: soap, soapui, magento2

I need to fetch Customer Information from a third party http://91.209.142.215:2803/SXYMAGENTO/?wsdl. I can connect it using SOAPUI and get desired response, but I am not able to connect it via Magento2. So far I tried

```
    $requestData = [
              'pageSize' => 1,
              'pageNumber' => 1
          ];
    $webservice_url = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/MAGENTO/?wsdl';
        $token = 'm31oix12hh6dfthmfmgk7j5k5dpg8mel';
        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token)
            );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $soapClient = new \SoapClient($webservice_url, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);
    $collection = $soapClient->RetrieveCollection($requestData);
    print_r($collection);
    die();
```

but this outputs Product data(maybe this is set as default), not customer data. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure this out and posting the answer so that it may help anyone craving a solution or fighting with a deadline.

1. Extend SoapClient and you can change Action, Request, and location

   ```
   namespace Namespace\SoapModule\Api;

   class CustomSoap extends \SoapClient
   {


     public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
     {
       $action = 'Your/Action/Obtainedfrom/SOAPAction';
       $this->__last_request = $request; //Optional. You should do this if you dont want to get confused when print $request somewhere else in the module
       return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);       
     }
   }
   ```
2. construct an object of above class wherever required

   ```
   public function getCustomersDetails($page_size, $page_number)
   {
       $requestData = [
         'pageSize' => $page_size,
         'pageNumber' => $page_number
        ];
   ```

   ```
    $data = $this->client->__soapCall('RetrieveCollection', [$requestData]);
    return $this->client->__getLastResponse();
   ```

   }

   public function statementBalance()
   {
       $responsexml = $this->getCustomersDetails(1, 1);
       $xml = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $responsexml);
       @$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
       $json = json_encode($xml);
       $responseArray = json_decode($json, true);
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($responseArray);
   }

Happy coding!